# how to resolve error in sas eg error: @echo off statement is not in proper order

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
sas error 180-322: statement is not valid or not used in proper order.

@echo off

@echo off
rem/\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*/
call d:/opt/----
```

please give me the soluion to resolve the error of @echo off

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. Please provide the code you used. Try to give us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Those lines do not look like SAS code.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have listed is DOS command line code, not SAS, as Tom mentioned. It is for a .bat or .cmd file. Calling it direct in SAS is not going to work. You can create a file with it and name that file .cmd or .bat then execute it via the SAS X command.

However, tell  us what you are trying to do and we might be able to help. Use PowerShell vs DOS command language, anyways.

Comment: @tom this is .bat file, how to work on ths file i want it to load the tables in the eg

Comment: I dont know what your bat file does so no way to help you. It is cut off. If this bat file was there vefore, you can execute from the cmd line. Not sure what it does, however.